# How to upload mpdf file after generating to s3 bucket in php

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, mpdf

Can I upload mpdf file to s3 server after generating.

```
$file_name = $pdf->Output(time().'_'.'E-Prescription.pdf','F');
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you have the AWS SDK installed in your project using composer; specifically...

```
composer require aws/aws-sdk-php
```

Yes you can, using the stream wrapper like this:

```
require "vendor/autoload.php";

$aws_file = 's3://bucketname/foldername/your_file_name.pdf';

//the folder is optional if you have one within your bucket

try {

    $s3->registerStreamWrapper();
    $mpdf->Output($aws_file, \Mpdf\Output\Destination::FILE);
}
catch (S3Exception $e) {

    $data['error'] = $e->getMessage();
    //show the error as a JSON callback that you can use for troubleshooting
    echo json_encode($data);
    exit();
}
```

You might have to add write permissions to your web server as follows (using Apache server on Ubuntu AWS EC2):

```
sudo chown -R www-data /var/www/html/vendor/mpdf/mpdf/src/Config/tmp
sudo chmod -R 755 /var/www/html/vendor/mpdf/mpdf/src/Config/tmp
```

Then edit the ConfigVariables.php file found at:

```
\vendor\mpdf\mpdf\src\Config
```

Change:

```
'tempDir' => __DIR__ . '/../../tmp',
```

To:

```
'tempDir' => __DIR__ . '/tmp',
```

Then create an empty folder named 'tmp' in that same directory. Then upload with joy.

Answer (score 2):

```
// Set yours config's
define("AWS_S3_KEY", "<your_key_here>");
define("AWS_S3_SECRET", "<your_secret_here>");
define("AWS_S3_REGION", "<your_region_here example:us-east-1>");
define("AWS_S3_BUCKET", "<your_bucket_folder_name_here>");

try {
    /*
    doc: https://github.com/mpdf/mpdf
    url/download: https://github.com/mpdf/mpdf/archive/development.zip
    */
    require_once 'mpdf/mpdf.php'; // load yout mdf libe
    $mpdf = new mPDF(); // set init object mPDF

    $nomeArquivo = md5('cliente_01'); // set file name and cripty this
    
    $mpdf->WriteHTML("Teste upload PDF in s3 bucket");

    /*
    doc: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-php/v3/developer-guide/getting-started_installation.html
    url/download: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/v3/download/aws.zip
    */
    require_once 'aws/aws-autoloader.php'; // set locate yout lib AWS

    $aws_file = 's3://'.AWS_S3_BUCKET.'/'.$nomeArquivo.'.pdf';
    
    $s3 = new Aws\S3\S3Client([
        'region' => AWS_S3_REGION,
        'version' => 'latest',
        'credentials' => [
            'key'    => AWS_S3_KEY,
            'secret' => AWS_S3_SECRET,
        ]
    ]);

    $s3->registerStreamWrapper();
    $mpdf->Output($aws_file); //Send yout mPDF File in s3-file-bucket
} catch (S3Exception $e) {
    die($e->getError().' => '.$e->getMessage();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To do this you could use the [AWS SDK for PHP](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/v2/guide/index.html).

First you will need to create a client using your profile credentials.

```
use Aws\S3\S3Client;

$client = S3Client::factory(array(
        'credentials' => array(
            'key'    => 'YOUR_AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID',
            'secret' => 'YOUR_AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY',
        )
    ));
```

And, if the bucket already exists, you can upload your file from the file system like this:

```
$result = $client->putObject(array(
    'Bucket'     => $bucket,
    'Key'        => $file_name,
    'SourceFile' => $pathToFile
));
```